# c# Daily Calorie Intake Calculator

Tags: c#, calculator

I am new to coding and am attempting to make an application that will calculate a persons **Base Metabolic Rate** based upon their gender, height, weight, and exercise amount. The application should take the information provided and run an equation based upon their gender to calculate their **BMR**. Next, it should take the person's **BMR** and multiply that depending on how often the person exercises.  So far, I have been able to make the application run a different equation based upon gender. However, I am unable to make the application take the answer from the first equation and multiply it by the amount exercised. I apologize if I am not being specific enough in my description. I am quite new to coding and really have no idea what I am doing.

Any and all help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
{
    public partial class calorieCalculator : Form
    {
        public calorieCalculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void calorieCalculator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string gender, exercise;
            double height, weight, age, malebmr, femalebmr; //variables
            decimal bmrmult;

            // get personal information
            height = double.Parse(heightTextBox.Text);
            weight = double.Parse(weightTextBox.Text);
            age = double.Parse(ageTextBox.Text);
            // select gender
            if (genderList.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                gender = genderList.SelectedItem.ToString();
                switch (gender)
                {
                    case "Male":
                        // perform calculation
                        malebmr = weight * 10 + height * 6.25 - age * 5 - 5 ;
                        bmrDisplay.Text = ("Your base metabolic rate burns " + malebmr + " calories");
                        break;
                    case "Female":
                        femalebmr = weight * 10 + height * 6.25 - age * 5 - 161;
                        MessageBox.Show("You should eat:" + femalebmr + "calories");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void caloriesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (exerciseList.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                string exercise;
                decimal bmrmult;
                exercise = exerciseList.SelectedItem.ToString();
                switch (exercise)
                {
                    case "Light exercise (1–3 days per week)":
                        bmrmult = 1.375M;
                        break;
                    case "Moderate exercise (3–5 days per week)":
                        bmrmult = 1.55M;
                        break;
                    case "Heavy exercise (6–7 days per week)":
                        bmrmult = 1.725M;
                        break;
                    case "Very heavy exercise (twice per day, extra heavy workouts)":
                        bmrmult = 1.9M;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I attempted to revise my code and do away with my second button. However, now I am getting an all new problem. My **BMR** is not multiplying by the `bmrmult` that it needs to. In fact, half the time when I click the button I get an output of 0. I know something must be wrong with my exercise if statement but I have no idea what.

Heres the new code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
{
    public partial class calorieCalculator : Form
    {
        double malebmr, femalebmr, calories;
        int bmrmult;
        string gender, exercise;
        double height, weight, age;//variables

        public calorieCalculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void calorieCalculator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }

        private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            //get personal information
            height = double.Parse(heightTextBox.Text);
            weight = double.Parse(weightTextBox.Text);
            age = double.Parse(ageTextBox.Text);
            //select gender
           if (genderList.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                gender = genderList.SelectedItem.ToString();
                switch (gender)
                {
                    case "Male":
                        //perform calculation
                        malebmr = (weight * 10 + height * 6.25 - age * 5 - 5);
                        calories = malebmr * bmrmult;
                        bmrDisplay.Text = ("Your base metabolic rate burns " + calories+ " calories");
                        break;
                    case "Female":
                        femalebmr = weight * 10 + height * 6.25 - age * 5 - 161;
                        MessageBox.Show("You should eat:" + femalebmr + "calories");
                        break;
                }
            }
           if (exerciseList.SelectedIndex !=-1)
            {
                string exercise;
                exercise = exerciseList.SelectedItem.ToString();
                switch (exercise)
                {
                                    case "Light exercise (1–3 days per week)":
                                       bmrmult = (int)1.375m;
                               break;
                                      case "Moderate exercise (3–5 days per week)":
                                         bmrmult = (int)1.55m;
                                        break;
                                    case "Heavy exercise (6–7 days per week)":
                                        bmrmult = (int)1.725m;
                                        break;
                                     case "Very heavy exercise (twice per day, extra heavy workouts)":
                                         bmrmult = (int)1.9m;
                                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe "the answer from the first equation" is the person's BMR right?

One quick way to solve this is by changing the scope of your `malebmr` and `femalebmr` variables.

Declare `double malebmr, femalebmr;` outside of your `calculateButton_Click()` function should let you use them in `caloriesButton_Click()`.

Comment: You are correct. I actually attempted to use your advice and moved those variables as well as `bmrmult`. Then I attempted to change the formula to                      `case "Male":
                        //perform calculation
                        malebmr = weight * 10 + height * 6.25 - age * 5 * bmrmult - 5;
                        bmrDisplay.Text = ("Your base metabolic rate burns " + malebmr + " calories");
                        break; ` However, I am now getting "Error CS0019 Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'".

Comment: That is a smart idea. However, I still cannot figure out how to tell the application to multiply the Female Or Male BMR by the amount of exercise. Basically, I cannot figure out how to retrieve the users answer and then multiply it by their amount of exercise. I honestly feel like my entire logic is screwed up on this application. I wanted to do an if statement that defines how much the BMR needs to be multiplied by. However, because the gender changes the answer, I cannot figure out how to turn that answer into a variable. At least... I think that is what I'm trying to say.

Comment: what does (int)1.375m do?
Try changing the type double to decimal, and make bmrmult decimal too

Comment: Now I'm getting Error CS0019 Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal' –